# Assigning values to multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I´m trying to assign values to a multidimensional vector, but I always get an "R6010 - abort()" error from visual studio.

What I want is an two dimensional vector, where the second dimension is exactly as large as needed. (Important because I don't now how many input values and I want to use later `myvector.at(i).size();`

So to formulate it short: Why is the following example not working?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

vector < vector < int > > Vektor;
Vektor.resize(10);
int tmp;

while (true) {
    cout << "Please enter a value: " << endl;
    cin >> tmp;
    int size;

    if (tmp > 0 & tmp < 11) {
        Vektor.at(tmp - 1).push_back(tmp);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        size = Vektor.at(i).size();
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            cout << "Value at " << i << " , " << j << " : " << Vektor.at(i).at(j) << endl;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: It should tell you where this error occurred. In any case, you should use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong indices in the lines:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    size = Vektor.at(i).size();
```

Change the lines to:

```
             |      ||
             v      vv 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    size = Vektor.at(i).size();
```

Answer (score 0):

As already answered by @RSahu, you use wrong indices in a loop. In stead of correcting the values, I'll suggest that you **avoid hard coded values**.

That can be done in several ways. By using vector.size() your code is easy to fix. Just use these two lines instead of your current two lines:

```
if (tmp > 0 & tmp <= Vektor.size()) {

for (int i = 0; i < Vektor.size() ; i++) {
```

An alternative way of printing could be

```
size_t i = 0;
for (const auto& v : Vektor)
{
    size_t j = 0;
    for (const auto e : v)
    {
        cout << "Value at " << i << " , " << j << " : " << e << endl;
        ++j;
    }
    ++i;
}
```